# How to upgrade Ubuntu and gnome without breaking existing settings?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, upgrade, system-settings

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for about 5-6 months, and have everything configured as per my liking. I use GNOME classic as the DE instead of Unity, and am comfortable with it. There are couple of extensions like having a 'show desktop' icon, windows like icon in the panel for applications that are open, weather indicator and lots of extensions like that.

lately I have been thinking about upgrading to 12.10 version. I am concerned about the below:

1. if I do an upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04 (instead of a clean install), will it affect any of the data that I have in my Ubuntu drive?
2. will doing an upgrade remove my gnome DE?
3. if gnome DE would still be present, would I have to setup the extensions and other personalisations again, or would those be preserved?

I want to upgrade to 12.10 AND use gnome 3.6 at the same time, without breaking any of the stuff I have configured in my current Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome 3.4. let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04 without breaking your settings, so long as you **do not** do a clean installation.

You can either upgrade using the upgrade manager or the command line, or you can manually upgrade by changing your sources to point to quantal instead of precise, and then manually upgrading the packages.

Comment: So all my installed packages will remain as such, and there would be no need to install again after the upgrade. am I correct? And once I am done with the upgrade, I just need to upgrade gnome to 3.6, and am assuming this won't break the installed extensions (unless those extensions are not yet supported). Correct?

Comment: @ubuntumon 12.10 is based on 3.6, so just upgrade, and as long as your extensions are supported they will work, yes.